# OpenCV throws error -213: Yolo9000 is not implemented in function 'RegionLayerImpl'

Tags: opencv, object-detection, yolo, darknet

all! I am working on object detection and computer vision related tasks. For a specific application, I would like to use YOLO 9000 model but I am unable to use it with DarkNet as I would normally do with standard YOLO models. I use this code script:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import time
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

img = cv.imread('image.jpg')

classes = open('yolo-9000/darknet/data/9k.names').read().strip().split('\n')

np.random.seed(42)

colors = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(len(classes), 3), dtype='uint8')

net = cv.dnn.readNetFromDarknet('yolo-9000/darknet/cfg/yolo9000.cfg', 'yolo-9000/yolo9000-weights/yolo9000.weights')
ln = net.getLayerNames()
ln = [ln[i - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
blob = cv.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1/255.0, (416, 416), swapRB=True, crop=False)
r = blob[0, 0, :, :]
net.setInput(blob)
outputs = net.forward(ln)
```

It works with yolov3 files but when I run this code block, it provides me with this error:

```
error: OpenCV(4.5.4) /tmp/pip-req-build-3129w7z7/opencv/modules/dnn/src/layers/region_layer.cpp:101: error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) Yolo9000 is not implemented in function 'RegionLayerImpl'
```

Do you have any idea for me to overcome this error and get bounding boxes from YOLO 9000? I will appreciate your help and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

"Not implemented"

OpenCV does not support `yolo9000.cfg`

Details: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/9705

And that's the only issue I've found mentioning `yolo9000`.

You could add an implementation to OpenCV. Or you could ask for one. Or you could see if any other library can run yolo9000 (you use python, so I'd look at pytorch and tensorflow).

Comment: Thanks for reply but I am unable to find a library that implemented it. There is only the ./darknet detector test like command to use the model.